Connection test to remote MySQL fails: what can I try further?
MySQL runs on remote  Windows VM.
VM is up and running, mysqld.exe too.
MySQL is while installation activated for TCP/IP access.
Port 3306 is in my.ini and in connectivity settings of MySQL.
Firewall opened while installation and freed in connectivity settings.
Connection test to IP succeed.
Test with powershell Test-Netconnection -ComputerName <IP> -Port 3306 fails.
Q: What can I try further to establish successful connection test?
Screenshot displays powershell with test, connectivity settings of MySQL and task manager.


What is the result of command netstat -an|findstr 3306?

You need to make sure:

my.ini have bind-address like this:


bind-address        = 0.0.0.0

This is for remote access anywhere.
You will need to add a remote user for Mysql so that you can connect using mysql client.
